# C# how to retain values after redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net

So what i want to know is that how do i retain the values after redirecting, where after clicking the back button brings me back to the first page. For example, if i store some values in page 1 then i click submit, which brings me to page 2. But in page 2 i want to click back. How do i retain the values that i have submitted in page 1? 
Also, what must i write in the btn_Click field? This is my code? What should I change

```
protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("AddStaff.aspx", true);
        Response.Redirect("AddStaff.aspx?" +strValues);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx it lists all the option for you

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways you can retain the value.

1. Using Cookie
2. Using Session
3. Using Query String
4. Using database

**For example let's look at how to set the Cookie**

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ValueToSave", "StackOverFlow");
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
 Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");
```

To Access the Cookie you can do as follows on Page_Load

> ```
> if (Request.Cookies["ValueToStore"] != null)
> {
>      string tempCookie = Request.Cookies["ValueToStore"].Value;
> }
> ```

**Using session you can achieve it as follows**
Save value to Session on Button Click

```
Session["ValueToStore"] = "StackOverFlow Session";
```

Retriving the value on Page Load

```
 if (Session["ValueToStore"] != null)
 {
     string val2 = Session["ValueToStore"].ToString();
 }
```